# RHEL 8 -- Configure TigerVNC server so it will start user sessions only if they try to connect

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, vncserver, tigervnc

I configured TigerVNC server on RHEL 8 according to the instructions provided by [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_the_desktop_environment_in_rhel_8/accessing-the-desktop-remotely_using-the-desktop-environment-in-rhel-8) and [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-configure-vnc-server-red-hat-enterprise-linux-8). I have configured it for several users and everything seems to be working fine.

The problem is that each remote VNC user's session is started right after the system starts, so even if some users have never logged in, their sessions are active. It looks like a waste of resources. (There are also a few other drawbacks of such approach for me.)

I want a specific user's session to be started only when that user tries to connect to the server via VNC. Is it possible to configure the TigerVNC server this way?